# Automatically return to my site after a Paypal payment

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I've setup a PayPal sandbox. I have created a "buy now" button with a cancel url and a finish url.  I have also added a custom notify_url variable.

I get notified when they press the "pay now" button, so that's good.
The problem is on the front-end:

> Q: How do I redirect them back to my site?

I realize that there is a link that says "Return to So and So's store", but I can't depend on the user to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not have Paypal open in another window so all they have to do is close the Paypal window and they are still on your site.

Comment: Thanks Crash!  No, the people that I'm programming for wouldn't know that it would be ok to close the window. It's got to go back to my site automatically.

Comment: Then you will have to create a alert box with a button in it that says, "Return to Site"?, right in the middle so they see it and maybe play a beep sound.

Comment: Seems like you are dealing with some dense people, why not put instructions right above the "pay now" button that says "When you are finished, click 'Return to.....store to return to website'.

Comment: Because they won't read it.  No kidding.  We've found that people are scanning for the next button to press and that they are not reading instructions.  The more instructions we add, the less they read them.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn Here's a trick, make a text scroll window with all your instructions in it, add a check box and then the pay now button, disable the checkbox until the user scrolls down the text window and which enables the checkbox and when that is clicked it enables the button. If they do that and still can't get back to your site then they are probably too dumb to operate your product.

Comment: I think I might have to upgrade to PayPal's Website Payments Pro.

Comment: @Crash_Override let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1710/discussion-between-cf-phillipsenn-and-crash-override)